# Gmail is showing suspicious link prompt for registration, forgot password or any other email in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, email, gmail, phpmailer

I am sending users forgot password or registration emails among others in WordPress. I rely on WordPress functions to send the mail and don't add any other text to them.

At first, I thought the prompt might be due to sender mail and sender name being set to wordpress@domain.com and domain. I added the following code to my `functions.php` file:

```
function wpb_sender_email( $original_email_address ) {
  return 'admin@domain.com';
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', 'wpb_sender_email' );

function wpb_sender_name( $original_email_from ) {
  return 'Domain';
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from_name', 'wpb_sender_name' );
```

However, this did not have any impact.

Next, I did some tests to see if I can get any information about the prompts. Here is the analysis of email headers for a [successful](https://mxtoolbox.com/Public/Tools/EmailHeaders.aspx?huid=7fd9796e-5f82-4e37-9129-63da8d344132) and [unsuccessful](https://mxtoolbox.com/Public/Tools/EmailHeaders.aspx?huid=f89c022e-b1d3-4ec0-beac-e85ef3d7594e) email.

I don't think it has anything to do with the text inside the emails because it is pretty straightforward and I did not make any changes to the default email text by WordPress.

> [Website Name] Password Reset Hello!
>
> You asked us to reset your password for your account using the email address [Username].
>
> If this was a mistake, or you didn't ask for a password reset, just ignore
>   this email and nothing will happen.
>
> To reset your password, visit the following address: password_reset_url
>
> Thanks!

**One thing that is consistent between the emails which show the prompt is that they all are delayed by 4 or 5 minutes.**

Comment: Are you using https for your website? If not, that may be the reason.

Comment: @simon I am using `https`. :)

Comment: One thing that is bugging me is that the prompt is not shown for all emails so it does not seem have anything to do with the headers, email content, links or anything else.

Answer (score -1):

Because in the email there may be http links instead of the https, some time if we send the unsecured links that would be the one reason.